# custom sort order within a group of alerts with same type id

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

****************************EDITED**********************************************

I have the following code that does the following:

1. Group alerts with same alert type ID together
2. sort entire groups in a custom order specified by AlertSorterUtil
3. within a group sort by severity in a specific order.

I am having trouble with 3. Within a group, the elements(alerts) have to be sorted by severity which is an integer. In the order of severity's 1,2,3,4,5,0.

```
    var severityOrder = new[] { 1 ,2,3,4,5,0 };

            // All Alerts
            var alerts = new BPAlerts
            {
                AllAlerts = intakeAlerts.Select(
                    alert => new BPAlert
                    {
                        AlertTypeId = alert.AlertTypeId ?? 8100,
                        IsOverview = alert.IsOverviewAlert.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        Text = alert.AlertText,
                        Title = alert.AlertTitle,
                        Type = alert.AlertTypeId == 8106 ? "warning" : "report",
                        Severity = alert.AlertSeverity.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        Position = alert.Position.GetValueOrDefault()
                    })
                    .GroupBy(a => a.AlertTypeId)
                    .OrderBy(g => AlertSorterUtil.SortByAlertTypeId(g.Key))
                    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(a => a.Severity))
                    //list of lists (groups) need to be converted to a single list
                    .SelectMany(g => g)
                    .ToList()
            };

            if (!intakeTexts.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                foreach (BusinessReportCustomText text in intakeTexts)
                {
                    var alert = new BPAlert
                    {
                        AlertTypeId = text.CustomTextSectionId,
                        IsOverview = false,
                        Text = text.CustomText,
                        Title = Utils.CustomTextTitleGenerator.getTitle(text.CustomTextSectionId)
                    };
                    alerts.AllAlerts.Add(alert);
                }
            }

            alerts.TotalAlertCount = intakeAlerts.Count;

            return alerts;
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks find - is the problem what happens with `0` severity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are sorting the groups with this lambda:

```
g => g.OrderBy(a => a.Severity)
```

you need to modify the return value of the lambda to produce the order needed. Using your provided

```
var severityOrder = new[] { 1 ,2,3,4,5,0 };
```

you could use

```
g => g.OrderBy(a => Array.IndexOf(severityOrder, a.Severity))
```

Alternatively, you can mathematically transform `Severity` into `severityOrder`:

```
g => g.OrderBy(a => (a.Severity+5) % 6)
```

Finally, you could preserve the flexibility of the first approach but avoid the search overhead of `Array.IndexOf` by creating a mapping:

```
var severitySortMap = new[] { 6, 1,2,3,4,5 };
g => g.OrderBy(a => severitySortMap[a.Severity])
```

Answer (score 0):

so using Thenby twide does not disrupt the order in any way. This solved my problem:

```
 var alerts = new BPAlerts
        {
            AllAlerts = intakeAlerts.Select(
                alert => new BPAlert
                {
                    AlertTypeId = alert.AlertTypeId ?? 8100,
                    IsOverview = alert.IsOverviewAlert.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    Text = alert.AlertText,
                    Title = alert.AlertTitle,
                    Type = alert.AlertTypeId == 8106 ? "warning" : "report",
                    Severity = alert.AlertSeverity.GetValueOrDefault(),
                    Position = alert.Position.GetValueOrDefault()
                })
                .OrderBy(x => AlertSorterUtil.SortByAlertTypeId(x.AlertTypeId))
                .ThenBy(y => AlertSorterUtil.SortAlertBySeverity(y.Severity))
                .ThenBy(z => z.Text)
                .ToList()
        };
```